# Unity WaitForSeconds not Working c#

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine

I have been faced a problem in Unity. I have not change anything in my script or scene but the problem it self occurred. I am confused, also particules and animators doesn't work, too. When I reload the scene by a button, All scripts, particules and animators works perfectly.

```
void Start(){
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Intro") == null || PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Intro") != "1")
            Application.LoadLevel ("dragonIntro");

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Ads") == null)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Ads", 0);

        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetString("language")==""){
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("language",Application.systemLanguage.ToString());
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
        Debug.Log ("test");
        StartCoroutine(rainMe());

 }




IEnumerator rainMe(){
        Debug.Log ("test2");
        float myWait = Random.Range(3f,6f);
        Debug.Log ("test3");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(myWait);
        Debug.Log ("test4");
        isRain = 0;
        SendMessage("lightMe");
    }
```

Test4 is not seem in the console.

**Note: I tried to fix it with my recovery files but the problem continues**

OK! I solved the problem.timeScale caused the problem.

Who will face with this problem can solve it easy by this answer

```
void Start(){
        Time.timeScale= 0;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

Comment: Please add your solution as the answer to your question, as per this guideline: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: A future tip, don't manipulate Time.timeScale for pause items. I've learned the lesson the hard way, it does some funky things. The best thing to do is save the state of all objects, or have a static public variable or class that emulates a state machine. If paused state (global static), then skip the content in Update() LateUpdate() FixedUpdate(). You get the drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is that I relased that, I reset Time.timeScale, firstly set "0", then set again 1

```
void Start(){
        Time.timeScale= 0;
        Time.timeScale = 1;

}
```

Comment: Great! Now you can accept this answer as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A future tip, don't manipulate Time.timeScale for pause items. I've learned the lesson the hard way, it does some funky things. The best thing to do is save the state of all objects, or have a static public variable or class that emulates a state machine. If paused state (global static), then skip the content in Update() LateUpdate() FixedUpdate(). You get the drift.